# how to un-exclud directory in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

[image: excluded directory]

I am trying to un-exclud directory in pycharm, someone know how to do so?

Comment: Right click → "Mark as..."…?

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in comments, you can do this:

```
right-click on the folder -> Mark directory as -> Cancel Exclusion
```

Otherwise you can click on

```
File -> Settings -> Project -> Project Structure
```

Then click on the excluded folder and click on the red folder at the top on the window

[image]

Comment: "Mark directory as" no exist

Comment: Answer edited, please check